# One button on left side other on the right

Tags: android, xml, button

I know there are questions like this but most the time it seems their problem is they didn't align the Layouts as fill parent. Well I did so I am not sure why my buttons still won't do it. Could it be because of all the layouts I use?

```
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:background="@drawable/face">

  <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="100dp" android:gravity="center">
  <ImageView android:layout_marginLeft="15dp" android:layout_marginRight="15dp" android:id="@+id/eyes" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/eyes1" />
        <LinearLayout android:layout_marginTop="50dp"  android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:orientation="horizontal">
            <Button android:id="@+id/eyesback" android:layout_width="50dp" android:layout_height="50dp" />
            <Button android:id="@+id/eyesforward" android:layout_height="50dp" android:layout_width="50dp" android:layout_gravity="right"></Button>
        </LinearLayout>
  </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Its probably something simple I missed too. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one

```
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:background="@drawable/face">

  <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="100dp" android:gravity="center">
  <ImageView android:layout_marginLeft="15dp" android:layout_marginRight="15dp" android:id="@+id/eyes" android:background="@drawable/eyes1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <RelativeLayout android:layout_marginTop="50dp"  android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:orientation="horizontal">
            <Button android:id="@+id/eyesback" android:layout_width="50dp" android:layout_height="50dp" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>
            <Button android:id="@+id/eyesforward" android:layout_height="50dp" android:layout_width="50dp" android:layout_gravity="right" android:layout_alignParentRight="true"></Button>
        </RelativeLayout>
  </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I have simply  change teh LinearLayout into Relative layout and set properties to one button to get alighted left another one to right.

Answer (score 1):

```
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:background="@drawable/face">

  <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="100dp" android:gravity="center">
  <ImageView android:layout_marginLeft="15dp" android:layout_marginRight="15dp" android:id="@+id/eyes" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/eyes1" />
            <Button android:id="@+id/eyesback" android:layout_width="50dp" android:layout_height="50dp" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>
            <Button android:id="@+id/eyesforward" android:layout_height="50dp" android:layout_width="50dp" android:layout_gravity="right" android:layout_alignParentRight="true"></Button>
  </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

try it out

Comment: Thanks but it still didn't move them.

Comment: you want that one button to the left of parent and one to the right, then it is working fine

Answer (score 0):

Check this: this is suitable example for your requirement.

http://androidcodesnips.blogspot.com/2011/09/showing-buttons-on-either-side-of.html